# VBA Coding to add a row when the first value greater than # is found ( but only the first )

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a vba code that will look in Column D, and when the number in the column goes from a 7 digit number to an 11 digit number it will add 2 rows, either below the lower number or above the higher number.

So example:

1656340 
1656352 
1656389 
3156603873 
3156690671 
3156738131

Column D is in numerical order.

The next obstacle is when the number jumps from an 11 digit number to a 17 digit number with 2 hyphens through it.

Example:

3165694674 
3165694674 
3168190042 
026-1924781-2157120 
026-6908033-4106726 
028-8563479-8783525

The end result should have a 2 row gap between these length of numbers.
Sadly 2 of these sets of numbers are randomly generated so will not always ascend in value but will always have this many digits to their code.

Please let me know if further information is required, I'm a vba noob still but i'll do my best!

TIA

I have an offset code I've been using for another purpose that I can't get my head around to make work for this which is:

```
Sub AddingBreakRows()

Dim R As Range
Set R = Range("I2:I400")
Dim FR As Integer
Dim LR As Integer

FR = 1 ' First Row in R
LR = R.Rows.Count ' Last Row in R

Dim Index As Integer

For Index = LR To FR Step -1
If Not IsEmpty(R(Index)) Then
    R(Index).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
End If
Next

End Sub`
```

Comment: You can use `Like("#######")`, `Like("###########")` and `Like("###-#######-#######")` to check for those value types.

Comment: I did this: For Index = LR To FR Step -1
If cell.value = Like ("#######"), Like ("###########") and Like ("###-#######-#######")
    R(Index).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert *and it didn't work :(

Comment: My comment was meant to point you in the right direction: it's not a line of literal code.

Comment: Oh.. i am looking for help on the code as i mentioned I'm very much a noob to all of this so don't really understand how to just put stuff in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```vb
Sub AddingBreakRows()
    Const V7DIGITS = "#######"              '7 digit pattern
    Const V11DIGITS = "###########"         '11 digits
    Const V17DIGITS = "###-#######-#######" 'digits with dashes
    
    Dim rng As Range, ws As Worksheet, arr, r As Long, vU, vL, ins As Boolean
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    
    Set rng = ws.Range("I2:I" & ws.Cells(rows.count, "I").End(xlUp).row)
    arr = rng.Value 'get all values as array (faster)
    
    'loop over the array of values from the bottom up
    For r = UBound(arr, 1) - 1 To 1 Step -1
        vU = arr(r, 1)       'upper value
        vL = arr(r + 1, 1)   'lower value
        'Does the pattern change here, in one of the ways we're
        '   looking for?
        If (vU Like V7DIGITS And vL Like V11DIGITS) Or _
              (vU Like V11DIGITS And vL Like V17DIGITS) Then
            rng.Cells(r + 1).Resize(2).EntireRow.Insert
        End If
    Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I'm getting a Run time error '9' Subscript out of range

Comment: If you’re getting an error it’s useful to tell us which line.   Do you have a worksheet named “Data”?   That was just an example and you may need to make a change there.

Comment: Hi there,  cheers for getting back to me! I don't have a worksheet called Data, the sheet is called 'Test' and the file name is 'testy'. I only have one sheet in the file. I tried to change Data to my Sheet name but that didn't work.

Comment: Oops sent the comment too quickly, the error doesn't come up with a specific line it comes up as a window with the error showing up. When I changed the "Data" to "Test" no error came up but it doesn't do anything when i try it.

Comment: The sample data you posted has 10digits, not 11, in the middle format.